# GraphQL - Optional relatedTo value

Tags: categories, relations, relatedto, graphql

I have a component which lists events and can be configured to filter by category.

Query:

```
query Events($filter: [String]) {
  entries(
    section: "event"
    relatedToCategories: {group: "group", slug: $filter}
  ) {
    __typename
  }
}
```

Variables:

```js
{
    "filter": null
}
```

The filtering is working fine in most cases except with events that don't have a group category. I haven't found any value for `$filter` that fetches those. Setting it to an empty array or null only gets the events that have at least one category.

What's the correct approach?

**Update**

I also tried passing the entire filter object to the query:

Query:

```
query Events($filter: [CategoryCriteriaInput]) {
  entries(
    section: "event"
    relatedToCategories: $filter
  ) {
    __typename
  }
}
```

Variables:

```js
{
    "filter": [{group: "group", slug: "some-slug"}]
}
```

This works when a filter is set but not without one.

Passing `null` or `[]` throws this error: `Calling unknown method: craft\\elements\\db\\EntryQuery::relatedToCategories()`
Passing `[{}]` again only returns the entries which have any category set.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The second option (sending the whole `filter` as a variable) but instead of passing `null` or `[]` simply omitting it (or setting it to `undefined`) worked. Not sure why `null` and `undefined` act differently though.